# Rename a package in Android Studio

Tags: android

I tried to upload my android app built by Android Studio to Google play and got back a message "You need to use a different package name because your package name already exists in Google Play".
How do I change the package name by using Android Studio, please?

Comment: I use com.example.app

Comment: may you dont understand me :) , I didn't write it like "com.example.app" I mean like this form , i write it "com.aliapp.firstapp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open project structure view (on the left) -> Navigate to the package you want to rename -> Open context menu and choose Refactor -> Rename.